# How long do you have to collect a unpaid debt?

Tags: contract-law, business, oregon

If a client refuses to pay an invoice for work completed, how long do you have to file a claim? I have a written contract but they sent me a letter canceling the agreement.

Comment: Which jurisdiction?

Comment: @TimLymington U.S..Oregon, Curry County

Comment: https://statelaws.findlaw.com/oregon-law/oregon-civil-statute-of-limitations-laws.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statute of limitations in Oregon appears to be six years (per the link provided by Nate Eldgredge in the comments). This would be extended if there was a partial payment or written affirmation of the debt by the debtor.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the link, but couldn’t interpret.